# No module named lxml.html while running python script on Fedora

Tags: python, linux, lxml, fedora

I'm trying to run a python script on Fedora Server. I'm getting the following error.

```
/usr/bin/python report_generation.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "report_generation.py", line 9, in ?
import lxml.html
ImportError: No module named lxml.html
```

Doing some research, I found it needs python-lxml package to run the script. This machine already have some lxml installations. But, I'm not able to make this work.

```
yum search libxml

libxml2.i386 : Library providing XML and HTML support
libxml2.x86_64 : Library providing XML and HTML support
libxml2-devel.i386 : Libraries, includes, etc. to develop XML and HTML applications
libxml2-devel.x86_64 : Libraries, includes, etc. to develop XML and HTML applications
libxml2-python.x86_64 : Python bindings for the libxml2 library
libxslt.i386 : Library providing the Gnome XSLT engine
libxslt.x86_64 : Library providing the Gnome XSLT engine
libxslt-devel.i386 : Libraries, includes, etc. to embed the Gnome XSLT engine
libxslt-devel.x86_64 : Libraries, includes, etc. to embed the Gnome XSLT engine
libxslt-python.x86_64 : Python bindings for the libxslt library
```

Also, it says all of them are up to date when I tried to install the packages. For some reason, its not picking up the lxml module and throwing this error while running the script.
I'm new to both Linux and Python. Please provide me any clue to debug this issue.

Comment: I'm guessing that `libxml2-python` is not actually `lxml` at all, but the bindings that come with `libxml2`. As [the docs](http://www.xmlsoft.org/python.html) say, "The distribution includes a set of Python bindings, which are guaranteed to be maintained as part of the library in the future… Note that some of the Python purist dislike the default set of Python bindings, rather than complaining I suggest they have a look at lxml the more pythonic bindings for libxml2 and libxslt…"

Comment: @abarnert My installed python version is 2.7.1. When I tried yum install python-lxml, it fails with error No package python-lxml available. Nothing to do. Is there any other alternative that I can install lxml.

Comment: Without knowing which version of Fedora you have and which repositories you've configured, I can't tell you whether it's possible to get `yum` to find it or what you need to do. But my answer has links to an rpmfind search that will show you exact which distros do have such a package, and also tells you have to install it via `pip` if your distro doesn't have one. Is that not enough information?

Comment: Also, if you need further help finding packages, enabling repositories, etc., you probably want a site for help administering Fedora (maybe http://superuser.com?), not a site for programming help.

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo yum install python-lxml
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

Comment: Given the OP's avowed newness, some explanation with your one liners might help him.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the [`libxml2-python`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libxml2-python) package, it's pretty clearly the stock Python bindings for `libxml2`, not the third-party `lxml` bindings. These are *not* the same things, and they're maintained entirely separately.

As [the docs](http://www.xmlsoft.org/python.html) say:

> The distribution includes a set of Python bindings, which are guaranteed to be maintained as part of the library in the future, though the Python interface have not yet reached the completeness of the C API.
>
> Note that some of the Python purist dislike the default set of Python bindings, rather than complaining I suggest they have a look at lxml the more pythonic bindings for libxml2 and libxslt and check the mailing-list.

---

How can you tell that `libxml2-python` is the former rather than the latter? Well, the links are to http://xmlsoft.org rather than to http://lxml.de. And if you look at the [files](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/mageia/cauldron/x86_64/media/core/release/libxml2-python-2.9.1-2.mga4.x86_64.html), it installs things with names like `libxml2.py`, not `lxml`.

So, you can't import lxml because you didn't install lxml.

According to rpmfind, there are [`python-lxml`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-lxml&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=) packages for a variety of distributions. If there's one for yours, just install that, instead of (or in addition to, if you want both) `libxml2-python`.

If not, you will probably want to install it with [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html). Assuming you already have `pip` installed, just do this:

```
sudo pip install lxml
```

Comment: Thanks @abarnert  for the clear info. This is my Fedora version.
uname -a
Linux porthos 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jun 23 10:52:51 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Unfortunately I don't have pip installed on my machine. I need to search for its installation process now. As I said earlier, This is first time on Linux..its both frustrating and exiting.

Comment: @SatishJonnala: That doesn't tell me your Fedora version, it tells me your linux kernel version. To install `pip`, you should be able to just `yum install python-pip` or similar. If not, you can install it manually. At any rate, as I explained in a comment on the question, SO is not a good place for helping you administer your Fedora system.

Comment: I got .... src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @user391339: If you have a new question, click the New Question button, don't add a comment to a marginally related question from half a year ago. And when you do so, include more information. What platform (and distro, if Linux) and version are you on? What version of Python? What exactly did you type? And so on. (But I can give you a quick guess: You're on some distro that has separate packages named, e.g., `python34` and `python34-devel`, and you  need the latter if you want to build any C extension modules, like `lxml`.)

Answer (score 3):

The `lxml` package needs to be installed separately from any `libxml` libraries you may have installed. Use `pip install lxml` (optionally prefixed by `sudo` to install globally) to install it.

Comment: No, `import lxml.html` is just fine.

Comment: This same script is working perfectly on other machines where the lxml is installed correctly. I suspect the problem is the lxml installation on my machine. Thanks though.

Comment: @abarnert I've updated my answer to remove the offending `import` statement :)

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down but @MattDMo is correct!!! I got error "ImportError: No module named lxml.html.clean" and After running "pip install lxml" it resolved. Thank you very much sir MattDMo!